# Reordering single column in dataframe, without reordering the whole table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this

```
set.seed(42069)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(50), nrow = 10, ncol = 5))
names(df) <- paste0(rep("variable_", 5), 1:5)

| variable_1| variable_2| variable_3| variable_4| variable_5|
|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|  0.0975792|  2.2732604|  0.7981710|  0.1009557|  0.5469156|
|  1.4837063|  4.8105384|  0.3379726|  0.4386950|  0.8297455|
|  0.4580504|  0.0611627|  0.2248929|  0.5248615|  0.3160315|
|  0.1399439|  0.0805528|  0.1659186|  2.8510678|  0.5632555|
|  0.3829142|  0.6337043|  0.3341908|  0.2989038|  0.4339512|
|  6.5265164|  1.0946979|  1.7983602|  0.0435821|  0.6222236|
|  0.7618944|  1.4892511|  1.2600329|  0.4313751|  0.5948537|
|  0.5911888|  0.1326767|  0.7368028|  0.9389244|  0.6276355|
|  0.6227433|  0.1099597|  1.0445907|  0.1304709|  3.1539861|
|  0.0617808|  0.3641891|  1.2629195|  0.2675279|  1.5714020|
```

I would like to arrange columns 2 and 4 in ascending order, but leaving the other variables as they are

This is the output I am looking for:

```
| variable_1| variable_2| variable_3| variable_4| variable_5|
|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|  0.0975792|  0.0611627|  0.7981710|  0.0435821|  0.5469156|
|  1.4837063|  0.0805528|  0.3379726|  0.1009557|  0.8297455|
|  0.4580504|  0.1099597|  0.2248929|  0.1304709|  0.3160315|
|  0.1399439|  0.1326767|  0.1659186|  0.2675279|  0.5632555|
|  0.3829142|  0.3641891|  0.3341908|  0.2989038|  0.4339512|
|  6.5265164|  0.6337043|  1.7983602|  0.4313751|  0.6222236|
|  0.7618944|  1.0946979|  1.2600329|  0.4386950|  0.5948537|
|  0.5911888|  1.4892511|  0.7368028|  0.5248615|  0.6276355|
|  0.6227433|  2.2732604|  1.0445907|  0.9389244|  3.1539861|
|  0.0617808|  4.8105384|  1.2629195|  2.8510678|  1.5714020|
```

I have tried:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(variable_2, variable_4), funs(arrange(.)))
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is what you want? This will make this data.frame just a bunch of number and doing anything with it beyond this point will be... dubious at best.

Comment: Absolutely sure. I'm generating cumulative gains charts

Comment: Just use `funs(sort(.))` instead of `arrange`

Comment: Thanks - want to write it up as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [AndrewGustar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758280/reordering-single-column-in-dataframe-without-reordering-the-whole-table/50759067#comment88524569_50758280), this works:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(variable_2, variable_4), funs(sort(., decreasing = F)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cbind`

```
set.seed(42069)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(50), nrow = 10, ncol = 5))
names(df) <- paste0(rep("variable_", 5), 1:5)

df<-data.frame(cbind(df[,c("variable_1","variable_3","variable_5")],variable_2=df[order(df$variable_2),c("variable_2")],variable_4=df[order(df$variable_4),c("variable_4")]))[,paste0(rep("variable_", 5), 1:5)]
```

There definitely must be a neater way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
df_2 <- apply(df, 2, function(x) x[order(x, decreasing = T)])
```

Comment: adapting that for a more dplyr way, this would work: `df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(variable_2, variable_4), funs(.[order(., decreasing = F)]))`